# BufferedInputStream generated from Socket missing data

Tags: java, client-server, inputstream

Hello I have a problem with DataIn/OutStream generated from BufferedIn/Out/Streams. When I send file through the stream to the server, there is missing data, When I send 2681200 to the server, the server get only 2678816 bytes. I dont know what I did wrong. here the code for both. I see a lot of post saying that BufferedStreams are preferred to send files big files (50MB) so that's why I'm using it.

The Client part:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            String password = "test";
            SecretKey keyGenerated = CryptoUtils.getKeyFromPassword(password);
            File inputFile = new File("test_file.pdf");
            File receivedFromServer = new File("confirmation.pdf");
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 3333);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            FileManagement.sendFile(new FileInputStream(inputFile), out);
            OutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(receivedFromServer);
            FileManagement.receiveFile(in, outFile, 2681200);
            out.close();
            outFile.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException |
                IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The server part:

```
    public static void receiveFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, long fileLength) throws IOException {
        int readFromFile = 0;
        int bytesRead;
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[64];
        while((readFromFile < fileLength)){
            bytesRead = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
            readFromFile += bytesRead;
            outputStream.write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            System.out.println(readFromFile);
        }
    }

    public static void sendFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        int readCount;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
        //read from the file and send it in the socket
        while ((readCount = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        File file = new File("servers-files.pdf");
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3333);
        Socket socket = ss.accept();
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outSocket = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
        OutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
        FileManagement.receiveFile(dataInputStream, outFile, 2681200);
        FileManagement.sendFile(new FileInputStream(file), outSocket);
        dataInputStream.close();
        outFile.close();
        socket.close();

    }
```

Comment: You're not closing `outFile` on your server before you read from it. You also don't need the `DataInput/OutputStreams`, they're unnecessary wrappers around the buffered streams.

Comment: @Kayaman If I close outFile in the server before read on it I will not be able to write on it

Comment: @user16320675 FileManagement is just at tool to send file through Stream, I will test flush() after sending.

Comment: If you don't close the stream after writing, you won't write all the bytes. The code is extremely brittle and bug prone.

Comment: I'm using Windows 11 with antivirus disabled

Comment: I create a count in sendFile method, and I sum up every bytes read. That's how I how much byte to read.

Comment: @user16320675 but there's a good reason to close the stream. Flushing is unnecessary when you're going to close the stream anyway. But I'm not forcing him to write correct code.

Comment: I'm a little confused ^^, Can you tell me what I need to change in which line please. Thank both of you anyway for your help

Comment: @user16320675 no the filestream, not the socket stream. They're writing to a file, then reading from it without having closed the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: @user16320675 that is the problem.

Comment: I'm a little confused ^^, Can you tell me what I need to change in which line please. :)

Comment: @user16320675 if you read fine from an unclosed and unflushed file then you're getting lucky.

Comment: That's not working, anyway I will read a book in Java. Thank both of you for your time